# Split Google Sheets Cells into Multiple Rows Based on a Delimiter

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to come up with a function that will split data stored in a cell into multiple rows based on a delimiter (in this case, "\n"). I found a really good solution here:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/60861/google-sheets-split-multi-line-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-row-e

However, this solution only allows you to split up ONE column into multiple rows; I need to split up multiple columns.

Here is an example of some data I have now:
[image: data]

Here is an example of what I would like the final product to look like:
[image: result]

I know I can get this result by using `=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(cell,CHAR(10)))` and then copying down the other cells, but I have a lot of data so I'd really prefer to automate this like in the above link. Any help you can give me is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please post everything you requirement for your question into your question.  Don't depend upon external links.....Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask], [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [mcve] and [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Answer (score 4):

**Restructure rows to accomodate multiple items in a single cell**

```
function restructureRows() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  const shsr=2;//data start row
  const rg=sh.getDataRange();//this includes one header row
  const dlm='\n';//cell delimiter
  let vs=rg.getValues();//this includes header row
  let hA=vs.shift();//this put the header row in hA
  var ttl={};//converts array indices to column names
  var a=0;//added row counter
  hA.forEach(function(h,i){ttl[i]=h;});
  //vs nolonger contains header row
  for(var i=0;i<vs.length;i++) {
    var robj={max:1,maxidx:''};
    for(var j=0;j<vs[i].length;j++) {
      var temp=vs[i][j].toString();
      //if data contain line feed then that row will be expanded
      if(vs[i][j].toString().indexOf(dlm)!=-1) {
        let t=vs[i][j].toString().split(dlm);//split cell on dlm
        robj[ttl[j]]=[];//row expansion object
        t.forEach(function(e,k){
          robj[ttl[j]].push(e);//push expanded cell data into obj property arrays
        });
        if(robj[ttl[j]].length>robj.max) {
          robj.max=robj[ttl[j]].length;//keeping record of the max number of delimited terms
          robj.maxidx=j;//never actually used this yet
        }
      }else{
        robj[ttl[j]]=[];
        robj[ttl[j]].push(vs[i][j]);//if no dlm the just same the one term
      }
    }
    if(robj.max>1) {
      for(var k=0;k<vs[i].length;k++) {
        const l=robj[ttl[k]].length;
        if(l>1 && l<robj.max) {
          for(let m=l;m<robj.max;m++) {
            robj[ttl[k]].push(undefined);//This section fills in the cells that had multiple dlms with undefined so that all columns have the same amount of terms in their array
          }
        }else if(l==1) {
          for(let m=1;m<robj.max;m++) {
            robj[ttl[k]].push(vs[i][k]);//this section fills in the cells that have no dlms with the same value for all rows
          }
        }
      }
      sh.insertRows(i+shsr+1+a, robj.max-1);//insert addtional row
      var oA=[];
      for(var r=0;r<robj.max;r++) {
        oA[r]=[];
        for(var k=0;k<vs[i].length;k++) {
          oA[r].push(robj[ttl[k]][r]);//This section loads data into the ouput array in preparation for a single setvalues() to load all new rows at one time.
        }
      }
      sh.getRange(i+shsr+a,1,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA);//load data
      a+=robj.max-1;//increment added row counter
    } 
  }
}
```

Animation:

[image]